# How to change windows 8.1 taskbar tabs color

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, colors

Is there a simple way of customizing the taskbar tabs color of windows 8.1 64bit?

Here's a pic for example:

[image: the picture]

So how to I change the color of tabs "news", "video", "weather" etc...?

Of course these tabs are not pinned... and I want to be able to change the text color, border color etc... How can I do this, please?

Comment: This is not possible. You will need a program that can do this, but I don't think one even exists. The program itself may support it, but only to a mild degree, as there are status colors. This was something that worked in windows 7 and 8 but has been removed in windows 10.

Comment: NPN, not possible natively. That's like trying to change the icon for Microsoft Word from blue to red.

Comment: NPN. But as far I was able to understand, the color is only a parameter when building the Modern UI app. So IMHO, theoretically you could be able to hex-edit the file and change that value, if you know where it is located. But practically the answer is no, if for nothing else, then at least due to copyright reasons (you cannot modify 3rd party files etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't - the text and color are corresponding to the "icons' that are representing each of the programs. If you look at your start screen, they will be the same:

[image]

Notice the video and music icons on the top right and matching them to the taskbar in your screen

Since these are Windows built-in programs, you can't change the tiles/icon colors or texts.